# R reducing a numeric vector for reporting

Tags: r, vector

I have no idea what the correct title here is that will make it easy for other to find this later on...

I am reporting on quality of data that is submitted to me. For example, I report on missing data where this not allowed. I refer to the actual rows which have missing data. Sometimes there is a lot of missing data is so long that my QA report is pages long. I would like to know how to shorten numeric vectors.

How do I reduce:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 55, 56, 57)


paste0("Missing data: rows ", paste0(x, collapse = ", "))
[1] "Missing data: rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 55, 56, 57"
```

to:

"Missing data: rows 1:10, 20:30, 55:57"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to `split` the `vector` by creatng a grouping column based on the `diff`erence of adjacent elements, convert to logical, taking the `cumsum` of the logical vector, and then loop over the `list` with `sapply`, `paste` the `range` (or `min/max` values), and finally `paste` with the prefix string

```
paste0("Missing data: rows ", toString(sapply(split(x, 
   cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 1))), function(x)  paste0(min(x), ":", max(x)))))
#[1] "Missing data: rows 1:10, 20:30, 55:57"
```

Comment: Perfect! I see the Q got closed as it was already answered somewhere else. I guess that confirms my lack of giving a good title... i didnt know what words to search for! Others might have the same issue though.